# Compiling error - deprecated extension

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I use Linux Ubuntu and when I try to a compile a simple C program that prints something on the screen using

```
#import<stdio.h>
```

I get this error

```
#import is a deprecated GCC extension.
```

How am I supposed to resolve this error?

Comment: Show exactly your program as some [MCVE]. Perhaps replacing `#import` by `#include` *might* be enough (or not). Without improvement your question is too broad for SO

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot (by showing some code, indented with four spaces at least in front of every line). Otherwise your question will get closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between #import and #include in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280248/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GCC's CPP documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Alternatives-to-Wrapper-_0023ifndef.html#index-_0023import):

> CPP supports a variant of ‘`#include`’ called ‘`#import`’ which includes a file, but does so at most once.

You can safely replace `#import` by `#include` if you make sure the file referred to is  using so called ["header-guards"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once-Only-Headers.html#Once-Only-Headers).

So the 1st two lines of the file to be `#include`d  should look like

```
#indef SOMETHING_UNIQUE_IN_THE_CONTEXT_OF_YOUR_PROJECT
#define SOMETHING_UNIQUE_IN_THE_CONTEXT_OF_YOUR_PROJECT
```

then 0 to many lines

```
/* C stuff here */
```

and finally the last line should be

```
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`#import<stdio.h>` - wrong

`#include<stdio.h>`- right